# How to combine/merge lots of unsaved excel documents into one?

Tags: excel, merge, copy-paste, mergesort, vba

Is there any way to merge/combine data from multiple unsaved excel documents so its neatly in one document?  Essentially I have lots of excel tabs open (all unsaved) and want to take columns `A1-A20` and `B1-B20` of all excels and place into one main document going downwards.  SO rather than have heaps of different tabs with the information, there will be one ‘master’ document with all the info.  So the master document could be book 1 or any other named excel.

Anyone have any idea how to go about this?

A lot of methods I’ve found involve saved files and it’d take hours to manually save them.  I know you can add macros to templates upon opening/creating files, however I have no idea how you’d auto save each document opened and give it a different name.

If description inadequate -
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/0opi8pyy095hsrb/Book1%20as%20per%20image.xlsx?dl=0][1]

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4d3g526zgbwrl4/Book%201%20image.png?dl=0][2]

Comment: (a) If the description is inadequate, improve the question - don't direct people to another site which may have changed the information at the link you point to (b) You should be able to loop `For i = 2 To Workbooks.Count` and copy the information to `Workbooks(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code on a Standard Module of the workbook where you want to copy data from all the opened workbooks.
Run the code and the code will copy Range("A1:B20") from all the opened workbooks into the sheet1 of the macro workbook.
If required tweak it as per your requirement.

```
Sub CopyDataFromEachOpenedWorkbook()
Dim swb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim sws As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Set swb = ThisWorkbook
Set sws = swb.Sheets(1)
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If Not wb Is swb Then
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.Range("A1:B20").Copy sws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
        Next ws
    End If
Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me it selectively works :/.  However it is good to use as needed